# SQL Query to overlap the sums using two tables, SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I'd so appreciate if someone can help with my query.

I have two tables - `Payments` and `Repayments`.

```
Payments:                              Repayments:    
DATE         SUM      IS_REPAYED       DATE         SUM
01/01/15     20 000    0               05/01/15     5 000
                                       06/01/15     10 000
```

I need to have a flag that shows if `Payment` sum is covered by `Repayment` sums, in this case, if `(5 000 + 10 000) covers 20 000`, now it's not.

But when new `Repayment` added, it is:

```
Payments:                              Repayments:    
DATE         SUM      IS_REPAYED       DATE         SUM
01/01/15     20 000    1               05/01/15     5 000
                                       06/01/15     10 000
                                       07/01/15     5 000
```

However, there can be a case, when `Repayments` exceed payment, it means that `Payment` is repayed and the rest `5 000 (25 000 - 20 000)` should be calculated as a `Repayment` for the **next** `Payment`, i.e:

```
Payments:                              Repayments:    
DATE         SUM      IS_REPAYED       DATE         SUM
01/01/15     20 000    1               05/01/15     25 000
01/02/15     10 000    0
```

and when new repayment comes:

```
Payments:                              Repayments:    
DATE         SUM      IS_REPAYED       DATE         SUM
01/01/15     20 000    1               05/01/15     25 000
01/02/15     10 000    1               05/02/15     5 000  (or more, ex. 6 000) then 1 000 goes to the next Payment
```

There is also a case when `Repayment` comes first, then next payment should have a flag:

```
Payments:                              Repayments:    
DATE         SUM      IS_REPAYED       DATE         SUM
                                       01/03/15     30 000
05/03/15     30 000     1
```

So how can I get this `IS_REPAYED` flag, when I query the tables at a certain time, using current situation of Payment/Repayment statement? I know I can make a logic for the flag in my application, would it be a better solution?

To have a view I've shown above, I use `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.DATE, t1.SUM, NULL AS IS_REPAYED /*?*/, t2.DATE, t2.SUM
FROM 
(   (SELECT t1.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) as seqnum
    FROM Payments t1
    ) t1 
   FULL OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT t2.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY DATE) as seqnum
   FROM Repayments t2
   ) t2
ON t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum
)
```

Comment: Excuse me if I'm asking the obvious, but do you mean that you want to add a IS_REPAYED column to your physical table, or is it just a result-set column?

Comment: The result-set column would fit best, the variable of type TABLE can be also used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. Updating `IS_REPAYED` to 0 or 1 in `PAYMENTS` table when repaymant amount is less or equal to than payment amount for that month.**

```
UPDATE PAYMENTS SET IS_REPAYED = S.IS_REPAYED
FROM
(
    SELECT P.[DATE],CASE WHEN  R.[SUM] = P.[SUM] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IS_REPAYED
    FROM PAYMENTS P 
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [DATE]), 0)AS DATE) [DATE],  SUM([SUM]) [SUM]
        FROM REPAYMENTS
        GROUP BY CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [DATE]), 0)AS DATE)
    )R
    ON DATEPART(MONTH,P.[DATE]) = DATEPART(MONTH,R.[DATE]) AND R.[SUM] <= P.[SUM]
)S
WHERE PAYMENTS.[DATE]=S.[DATE]
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b5deb9/1) to view result(repaymant amount is less than payment amount)
- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55ec14/1) to view result(repaymant amount is equal to payment amount)

**2. Updating `IS_REPAYED` to 0 or 1 in `PAYMENTS` table and insertion to both tables when repaymant amount is greater than payment amount for that month.**

Finds sum and groups to each month data in inner query, then compare it with payment table. Since we need this data for further insertions to both `PAYMENTS` and `REPAYMENTS` table, we use a temporary table.

```
SELECT P.[DATE] PAYDATE ,P.[SUM] PAYSUM ,R.[DATE] REDATE,R.[SUM] RESUM
INTO #NEWTABLE
FROM PAYMENTS P 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT  CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [DATE]), 0)AS DATE) [DATE],  SUM([SUM]) [SUM]
    FROM REPAYMENTS
    GROUP BY  CAST(DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, [DATE]), 0)AS DATE)
)R
ON DATEPART(MONTH,P.[DATE]) = DATEPART(MONTH,R.[DATE]) AND R.[SUM] > P.[SUM]
```

Now we find the difference and insert to `REPAYMENTS` table

```
INSERT INTO REPAYMENTS
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,PAYDATE) [DATE], (RESUM-PAYSUM) REAMOUNT
FROM #NEWTABLE
```

Similarly we find the difference and insert to `PAYMENTS` table

```
INSERT INTO PAYMENTS    
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,1,PAYDATE) [DATE], (RESUM+(RESUM-PAYSUM))-PAYSUM REAMOUNT,1
FROM #NEWTABLE
```

Since value in `REPAYMENTS` table is greater than `PAYMENTS` table we directly update value of table to 1 from temporary table.

```
UPDATE PAYMENTS SET ISREPAYED = 1
FROM
(
    SELECT PAYDATE FROM  #NEWTABLE
)N
WHERE PAYMENTS.[DATE]=N.PAYDATE
```

- [Click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b992b/4) to view the result

Comment: Feel free to ask for any changes :) @Gyuzal R

Comment: Thank you for patience and help!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I think that you can achieve that with the following sql query

```
SELECT t1.DATE, SUM(t1.SUM), SUM(t1.SUM) = SUM(t2.SUM) AS IS_REPAYED, t2.DATE, SUM(t2.SUM)
FROM Payments t1 FULL OUTER JOIN Repayments t2 ON t1.DATE = t2.DATE
GROUP BY t1.DATE
```